# Jquery: How to change image by clicking on corresponding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle, slidetoggle

Basically, all I am looking to do is have 4 blocks of content wrapped in div and then have each one of those correspond to an image and change the image when click on the div.  I know this should be really simple, but I have a limited knowledge of jquery, mostly rely on plugins. I don't want to change the info divs to a link if possible. Thanks

Here is my current markup; using foundation grid

```
<div class="feature-one row clearfix">
    <div class="three columns">
        <span class="twelve columns activities-1">
            <p class="marker"> Title of Service</p>
                <p>Longer description of services</p>
        </span>
        <span class="twelve columns activities-2">
            <p class="marker"> Title of Service</p>
                <p>Longer description of services</p>
        </span>
    </div>

        <div class="six columns" >
            <img id="activities-1" src="screenshot.jpg"/>
            <img id="activities-2" src="screenshot.jpg"/>
            <img id="activities-3" src="screenshot.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div class="three columns">
            <span class="twelve columns activities-3">
                <p class="marker"> Title of Service</p>
                    <p>Longer description of services</p>
            </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for the help!

UPDATE:Here is the final of what I have; I am sure it's not perfect and can probably be more concise, but I hope it helps anyone looking. For anyone who wants to clean it up, perhaps make it work with hoverIntent I welcome your additions

```
    $('.feature-one img').each( function() {
    $(this).hide().filter(":first-child").show();;
});
$('.feature-one span').on('hover click', function() {
    var sName = $(this).attr('id');
    $('img#' + sName).fadeIn(800);
    $('.feature-one img').not($('img#' + sName)).fadeOut(800);
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pMTEf/).

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('img').hide();
    $('span').on('click', function() {
        var sName = $(this).attr('id');
        $('img#' + sName).toggle(800);
    });
});
```

I've added the property `id` to each of the span element, as you can see on the fiddle link.

Comment: Why not $('img').hide(); instead of each?

Comment: hmm, that could be done too, yeah! I've been using `each()` a lot lately.

Comment: Thanks for the help you gave me a good headstart, i got to almost where i want to be...